Choosing Named Range via formula
So I have this formula:

At a high level, the formula goes like this:
If [Dynamic Array #1] = False, 0,

    Index(
        If [Dynamic Array #2] = 1, Named Range A, Named Range B    <-- Problem exists here
        Row,
        Column
    )

There's a Dynamic Array with ones and zeroes, and the formula should be using that to choose which named range it's going to index.
But the formula is always indexing Named Range A, and never Named Range B, even when the value means it should be.
Why?

The second IF function does not do what you're expecting to do. It does not iterate through each logical_test and return either Named_Range_A or Named_Range_B to the INDEX function each time. Rather, Named_Range_A and Named_Range_B are simply merged together (row by row), based on the results of each logical_test, and resized (if necessary) to be the same height as the logical_test array and the same width as each other. This single set of results is the only array that's being referenced by the INDEX function for each row_num and column_num provided.
As a workaround, try using the MAP function to iterate through the arrays together and process each value individually:
=MAP(IA10#, IF10#, HT10#, HX10#,
    LAMBDA(u,x,r,c,
        IF(u=FALSE, 0, INDEX(IF(x=1, RateCard_Small_Parcel_Ground_LBS_Reynosa, Old_RateCard_Small_Parcel_Ground_LBS_Reynosa), r+1, c+1))
    )
)

